# Testes unitários com NUnit

Tags: c#

Acabei de instalar em meu projeto o "Nunit" para testes unitários.

Instalei via Nuget, no console do VS2013.

Coloquei as anotações em cima dos meus métodos
fui em teste Explorer e dei um "Run ALL".

Esse "Run ALL" está só compilando meu projeto e não está me mostrar quais testes

passaram e quais falharam.

**OBS: Meu projeto já estava pronto.**

Meu código

```
using NUnit.Framework;

   [TestFixture]
    public class LogDAO
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Metodo para inclusão 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UserID"></param>
        /// <param name="Acao"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Test]
        public void InserirLog(string UserID, string Acao)
        {
            using (entidadesIUS entidades = new entidadesIUS())
            {
                LogUtilizacaoIUS log = new LogUtilizacaoIUS();
                log.UserId = new Guid(UserID);
                log.Acao = Acao;
                log.DataOcorrencia = DateTime.Now;

                entidades.LogUtilizacaoIUS.Add(log);
                entidades.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

> Meu teste Explorer só fica dessa forma como já tinha dito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só um adendo, quando você "toca" o banco de dados, não é mais um teste de unidade e sim um teste de integração. Há menos claro, que o save changes seja um "mock". http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve executar os métodos de teste no NUnit.

1- Abra o **NUnit**

2- No menu ***File*** clique *Open Project* e selecione a dll do seu projeto, exemplo SeuProjeto.dll. Serão exibidos os métodos de teste, marcados com `[Test]`.

3- Selecione o método e clique no botão *Run*.

Ele indicará em caso de sucesso ou não.

[image: Exemplo de resultado dos testes]

Comment: Onde eu baixo ele renan?

Comment: Melhor eu usá-lo assim mesmo.

Comment: Aqui http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=home você pode fazer download e encontrará a documentação também.

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço muito bem o ***NUnit*** mas olhando para o seu código destaco duas coisas:

1 - Você está utilizado a anotação `[TesteCase]` sem parâmetros, por isso o método não recebe quaisquer valores.

2 - Você declarou o método `InserirLog` ***static***

Faças estas alterações:

```
[TestCase("valor_para _userID","Valor_para_acao")]
public void InserirLog(string UserID, string Acao)
{
```

**Só mais uma nota:** Você não está a testar nada pois não vejo nenhum ***Assert***

Comment: quero testar somente o metodo mesmo, troquei para Test e retirei o static continua mesma coisa.

Comment: editei a minha pergunta.

Comment: Faça *click* com o botão direito do rato sobre o nome do método e procure por uma opção do tipo **Run Tests**

Comment: Eu sei que se eu clicar em File-->> New Project-->> Test --> Unit Test Project ele irá funcionar.
Porém meu sistema já está construído e não posso desfaze-lo.

Comment: O Run ALL era pra está funcuionando.

Comment: Você também instalou o ***NUnit Test Adapter for VS***?

Comment: Sim ele já vem no pacote do nuget.

Comment: É um sistema empresarial então não dá pra colocar todo o código dentro desse Unit Test Project.

Answer (score 2):

Se você instalar o runner para Visual Studio 2013, o resultado dos seus testes deve aparecer no test explorer, sem a necessidade de abrir o test explorer do NUnit.

Segue o link: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d

Lembrando que, isso seria desnecessário caso você utilizasse o framework da microsoft MSTest.